# Is there a way to download all resources from a Piazza class?

Tags: piazza

I am about to complete a course, for which 35+ files were uploaded to Piazza

Is there a way to download all the lecture notes and general resources, or do I need to manually download each of them?

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution that is based on a Bash script.

If you use [Link Klipper](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/link-klipper-extract-all/fahollcgofmpnehocdgofnhkkchiekoo) (Chrome extension) you can create a `txt` file with all the links containing get_resource.

Then you can run this script:

```
for path in $(cat piazza.txt)
do
    filename=$(curl -I $path | grep Location | awk '{ print $2 }' | cut -d'?' -f1 | cut -d'/' -f7)
    curl -L $path > $filename

done
```

Just rename the text file to `piazza.txt` or change it in the script.

Answer (score 0):

If your login uses MFA then it's a little more complicated. You can do it pretty easily with with Chrome like this.

- Login to site with Chrome
- Open Developer Tools and go the the Network Tab
- Go to the page listing your files
- Right click on the Name of the top level page you just opened
- Select "Copy as CuRL"
- Use this as a template for the "curl" command that @Snæbjörn Valur Lilliendahl gave